# Problems with formatting json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

As Response from the server i get:

```
{"vorname":["muss ausgefüllt werden"],"name":["muss ausgefüllt werden"]}
```

So what i do with this Json Array `xhr.responseText` is this:

```
   $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText), function( i, val ) {
            console.log(val[0]);
     });
```

Normally i would expect this output:

```
 vorname    
 name
```

But i get:

```
 muss ausgefüllt werden
 muss ausgefüllt werden
```

Why? And how do i fix it? Thanks

Comment: What you want is `i` not `val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why? And how do i fix it?

The result of `jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)` is an **object** and `$.each` passes the *name* of the property as first argument, and its *value* as second argument to the callback.

It seems you want to log the name, so you have to log `i`, not the value `val`:

```
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText), function( i, val ) {
   console.log(i);
});
```

The example in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is pretty self-explanatory IMO:

> If an object is used as the collection, the callback is passed a
>   key-value pair each time:
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>     "flammable": "inflammable",
>     "duh": "no duh"
> };
> $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
>     alert( key + ": " + value );
> });
> ```
>
> Once again, this produces two messages:
>
> ```
> flammable: inflammable
> duh: no duh
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just get the `key` name of property. I would suggest you to use simple [**for-in loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for (var item in jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)) {
    console.log(item )
}
```

**EDIT**

Currently you are printing the `value` where as you need to get the `key` name of property. So you should print `key` first argument of each callback. So you can use.

```
$.each(data, function(key, val ) {
   console.log(key);
});
```

[**DEMO** with JSON data including both for-in and $.each](http://jsfiddle.net/U2ejN/2/)

Comment: While this certainly provides a solution, it doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling, Sorry I was lazy not to provide explanation. I think code is self explanatory, thus skipped that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText), function (key, val) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

---

You have to return `key` of your **json object**, as per documentation for `$.each()`:

If an **object** is used as the collection (*in your case too*), the callback is passed a key-value pair each time.

```
var obj = {
   "flammable": "inflammable",
   "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) { // key returns key of json object.
   alert( key + ": " + value ); //    alert(flammable: inflammable);
});                             //----------^^key^^----^^-value-^^--
```

this alerts two times as

```
flammable: inflammable // alert(flammable: inflammable);
duh : no duh                //--^^key^^----^^-value-^^--
```

where item before `:` in the alert is the key in the json object and other is the respective value.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Can you provide an **explanation**?

Comment: @FelixKling i was writing about it.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(yourResponse)
for (var key in obj){
  console.log(key + ':' + obj[key])  
}
```

response :

vorname:muss ausgefüllt werden 
name:muss ausgefüllt werden

Answer (score 0):

Because you are printing VAL and not KEY.
Do have what you expect:

```
 $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText), function( key , val ) {
       console.log(key);
 });
```

[Here a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FuPzJ/1/).

**Explanation:**
If you take a look at [JQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

" [..] $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array [..] The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.[..] "